# Pass javascript array to server using jquery .post on submit and then print array in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, .post

HTML:

```
<form id="continue" action="summary.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Continue" >
</form>
```

JS/JQuery

```
$('#continue').submit(function(){
    var data = ["jon", "steve"];
    var nameArray = JSON.stringify(data);
    $.post("summary.php", { nameArray: nameArray });
});
```

PHP

```
$name = json_decode($_POST["nameArray"]);
print_r($name);
```

When I click the "Continue" button, I want to be redirected to the summary.php page and list the names.  Currently, I get an "Undefined index: nameArray error when the summary.php page is loaded.

I checked firebug and there is no POST. So it looks like nameArray isn't even being posted either. What's the solution?

Comment: You have a POST implementation in both HTML and JavaScript. Do you want to use ajax (`$.post`) or redirect (`<form>`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the correct way of handling data.

You are posting a page (leaving it) and doing an ajax post within? If you want to stay on the page, you use an ajax post. If you are posting data normally, you use a form post.

If you want to post the name jon or steve as an array you can use the following html

```
<input type="hidden" name="nameArray[]" value="jon" />
<input type="hidden" name="nameArray[]" value="steve" />
```

If you want to use ajax, then just dont do it on the submit of a form. You can do it on a submit, but then return false at the end of the function so the page will not be submitted (you will stay on the current page)